# Alternative to using the Google API PHP Client

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-api-js-client

I have set up a Google Connect for my website using a combination of the Google JS API and the Google PHP API.

The entire PHP API consists of 16MB+ of PHP files, tremendously slowing down my local development environment. I want to remove all this bloat and use only the JS API instead, sending it's retrieved values to PHP with AJAX. Is this possible?

My current working code looks like this, but I want to refactor the code to not use the PHP API at all.

### jQuery

```
gapi.load('auth2', function() {

    var scopes = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
    ];

    // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
    gapi.auth2.authorize({
        'client_id': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'cookie_policy': 'single_host_origin',
        'fetch_basic_profile': false,
        'ux_mode': 'popup',
        'scope': scopes.join(' '),
        'prompt': 'select_account'
    },
    function(googleResponse) {

        if ( googleResponse.error ) {
            return;
        }

        var data = {
            'action': 'social_connect_google',
            'access_token': googleResponse.access_token
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                if ( response.success === true ) {
                    console.log(response);                  
                }
            }
        });         
    });             
});
```

### PHP

```
/**
 * Connect to Google API and login, signup or link accounts.
 *
 * @since  1.0.0
 *
 * @return WP_User|NS_Error
 */
public function connect() {
    $client = new Google_Client();

    $credentials = json_decode('XXXXXXXXX', true);

    $client->setAuthConfig($credentials);

    // Set Access Token
    $client->setAccessToken($_POST['access_token']);

    $oauth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);

    if ( !$oauth2 ) {
        return new NS_Error('invalid_access_token', 'The access_token was invalid.');   
    }

    $google_user = $this->get_user($oauth2->userinfo->get());

    if ( $this->get_user_by_google_id($google_user) ) {
        return $this->login($google_user);

    } else if ( $this->get_user_by_google_email($google_user) ) {
        return $this->link_accounts($google_user);

    } else {
        return $this->signup($google_user);
    }
}
```

Basically, I need to transfer the OAuth2 part of the PHP code to be done in JavaScript, and then send the retrieved Google User data to PHP, skipping the need for the PHP API.

Can this be done, and is this a valid and secure way to go about things?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's valid and secure.

Generally it's your use case that determines whether OAuth is best done on client or on the server.

If your use case lends itself to server based OAuth, and the library size is an issue, then don't use the library. It's very easy to do OAuth by calling the 2 endpoints directly. On the other hand, if your use case works fine on the client, then go ahead and do client OAuth. Provided you are using https for the transfer of user data, there is no security downside.

Be aware that the biggest restriction on client-side OAuth is that you are not able to request a Refresh Token. This means that the authorization is only valid as long as the user is present, thus your server is unable to do work on behalf of the user if he is offline.

Comment: Could you update your answer to include these 2 mentioned endpoints, or include a link pointing me in the right direction? I've Googled but haven't been able to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Check out the dummy's guide here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54097179/authenticate-to-google-api-with-node-js?noredirect=1#comment95139432_54097179